# How do I express the sum $(1+k)+(1+k)^2+\ldots+(1+k)^N$ for $|k|\ll1$ as a series?

Tags: summation, power-series

Wolfram Alpha provides the following exact solution
$$ \sum_{i=1}^N (1+k)^i = \frac{(1+k)\,((1+k)^N-1)}{k}.$$
I wish to solve for $N$ of the order of several thousand and $|k|$ very small (c. $10^{-12}).$  When I do this on a computer in excel the software cannot handle it (because of truncation of significant figures) and the results are nonsense.

I thought to approximate the result using the first few terms of a series in increasing powers of $k$.  I can multiply out the first few terms and examine the patterns in the following **pyramid**...
$$(1+k)^1 =               k +1  $$
$$(1+k)^2 =        k^2  +2k +1  $$
$$(1+k)^3 = k^3  +3k^2  +3k +1  $$
$$(1+k)^4 =k^4+4 k^3+6 k^2+4 k+1$$
$$(1+k)^5 =k^5+5 k^4+10 k^3+10 k^2+5 k+1$$
$$(1+k)^6 =k^6+6 k^5+15 k^4+20 k^3+15 k^2+6 k+1$$

So for example, for $N=3$ we would obtain the sum
$$
S= k^3  +4k^2 +6k +1
$$

The results suggest a solution with a pattern of the form
$$
S = a + bk^1 +ck^2+dk^3...
$$

I can see that $a=N$.  The other coefficients increase monotonously and it might be possible to determine a formula for the coefficients from the pattern. Although the general pattern is not convergent, it is possible that for certain restricted ranges of $N$ and $k$ a convergent formula could be obtained.  If so then it is possible that a useful approximation of S can be obtained just by evaluating the first few terms in the series.

But is there a well-known general formula for the terms in this series or can one be derived algebraically from the original formula?

---

**UPDATE**

following on from the answer by User73985...

$$ S=\sum_{i=1}^N (1+k)^i = N + \sum_{j=2}^{N+1}\binom{N+1}{j}k^{j-1}$$
So
$$ S= N + \sum_{j=2}^{N+1}\frac{(N+1)!}{(N+1-j)!j!}k^{j-1}$$

then
$$ S= N 
+  \frac{(N+1)!}{(N-1)!2!} k^{1} 
+  \frac{(N+1)!}{(N-2)!3!} k^{2}
+  \frac{(N+1)!}{(N-3)!4!} k^{3} +...
$$

giving
$$ S= N 
+  \frac{(N+1)(N)}{2!} k^{1} 
+  \frac{(N+1)(N)(N-1)}{3!} k^{2}
+  \frac{(N+1)(N)(N-1)(N-2)}{4!} k^{3} +...
$$

thus
$$ S= N 
+  \frac{N^2+N}{2} k^{1} 
+  \frac{N^3-N}{6} k^{2}
+  \frac{N^4-2 N^3-N^2+2 N}{24} k^{3} +...
$$

For $N=1 to 10,000$ and $k= 2.40242 * 10^{-12}$ this formula can be truncated to
$$ S = N + \frac{N^2+N}{2} k^{1} 
$$
and then gives results very close to those expected. Because $k$ is so small relative to $n$ the terms in higher powers of $k$ can be ignored. Note that the coefficient of $k^1$ is consistent with that found by examination of the coefficients in the "pyramid" presented above.

Comment: Your parentheses are mismatched on the first formula.  Was the intention $\frac{(k+1)(k+1)^N-1}{k}$, or something different?

Comment: @Dan. Thanks, sorry, I meant something different. I have corrected the question.

Comment: $\binom{N+1}{j} = \dfrac{(N+1)!}{(N+1-j)!j!}$, not $\dfrac{(N+1)!}{(N-j)!j!}$.

Comment: @TonyK Aha! Bingo!. Many thanks for pointing it out:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using
$$ \sum_1^N (1+k)^i = \frac{(k+1)\,((k+1)^N-1)}{k}$$

(which since this is a geometric series is not hard to prove)
we get

$$ \sum_1^N (1+k)^i = \frac{\left(\sum_{j=0}^{N+1}\binom{N+1}{j}k^j\right) - (k+1)}{k}$$

$$ = \frac{1 + (N+1)k + \left(\sum_{j=2}^{N+1}\binom{N+1}{j}k^j\right) - (k+1)}{k}$$

$$ = N + \sum_{j=2}^{N+1}\binom{N+1}{j}k^{j-1}$$

Comment: ah yes, thankyou!

Comment: Thanks. It looks promising.  I am following on in an update section at the end of my question.

Comment: Please see the Update at end of the question. My expansion of your formula misses the mark but a similar formula gets very close to the expected values.

Comment: @steveOw: You made a mistake $-$ see my comment to your question.

Comment: @TonyK. You are right, many thanks.

Comment: This answer appears to be what I was seeking (see Update at the end of the question), many thanks :-).

Answer (score 3):

for $k<1$ we can use
$$
(1+k)^N \approx 1+ kN + \frac{N(N-1)}{2}k^2 + \frac{N(N-1)(N-2)}{3!}k^3
$$
thus

$$
\begin{align}
\sum (1+k)^i &\approx&\frac{(k+1)(1+ kN + \frac{N(N-1)}{2}k^2 + \frac{N(N-1)(N-2)}{3!}k^3-1)}{k}\\
&=&(k+1)\left(1+\frac{N-1}{2}k+\frac{(N-1)(N-2)}{3!}k^2\right)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: This is especially useful for ridiculously tiny $k$; the smaller $k$ is, the better the approximation.

Comment: I know right. Hopefully, this was what the OP intended to get an answer about. Thanks!

Comment: @Chinny84. Thanks. But in the range which I am interested $N$ ranges from 1 to 10,000 and I expect to see a non-linearity in S due to effect of $k^2$.

Comment: Expand terms in my first expression to include higher order terms in $k$? Does that help you ?

Comment: Although I'm familiar with the approximation in your first expression I'm not sure what you mean by expanding it to higher orders of k and applying that result thereafter.

Comment: @steveOw modified to include higher order terms thus the expansion now has orders up-to and including $k^4$.

Comment: The "pyramid" analysis in the (revised) question suggests that $ S=N +(1/2)(N^2+N) k^1 +...$ is the start of the solution.

Answer (score 2):

There is nowhere a converging series in sight. From the data given it seems that $N$ is large and 
$$p:=Nk$$
is very small. Therefore we may write
$$S={1+k\over k}\bigl((1+k)^N-1\bigr)={1+k\over k}\left(\bigl(1+{p\over N}\bigr)^N-1\right)\doteq{1+k\over k}(e^p-1)\ .$$
If  $N$ is not in the thousands use the first few terms of the binomial series:
$$\left(1+k\right)^N-1=\sum_{j=1}^\infty{N\choose j}k^j\ .$$

Comment: @Christian.Thanks. The logic looks good. But in Excel, although the values of S look approximately right as N increases from 1 to 10,000 there is a ripple of approximately +/-0.2 *10^{-5} superimposed. I think this is due to a problem with truncation in excel but Ihavent narrowed it down to a particular term yet.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach using binomial coefficients:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{N}(1+k)^i&=\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{r=0}^i \binom ir k^r\\
&=k^0\sum_{i=1}^N\binom i0+\sum_{r=1}^Nk^r\sum_{i=r}^N\binom ir\\
&=N+\sum_{r=1}^Nk^r\binom{N+1}{r+1}
\end{align}$$

---

NB - the result is the same as 
$$\qquad  N+\sum_{r=2}^{N+1}k^{r-1}\binom {N+1}r$$